# Histogramming the number of tasks in time intervals

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame which includes two columns containing start time and end time of a large number of tasks during a day.

My goal is to histogram the number of tasks occurring in intervals of 30 minutes (I may need to change the interval, but I think that would be easy).

Here is an example of my start and end times in a sample data frame:

```
StartTime <- c("8:30","8:25","10:15","11:30","12:15","12:30","1:00","2:35")

EndTime <- c("9:00","10:05","12:00","1:05","2:06","2:58","3:30","4:00")

TaskTimes <- data.frame(StartTime,EndTime)
```

I am challenged by this, because I have to take both start time and end time into account.

Is there an easy way to do this without building a temporary data frame containing the number of tasks in each time period?

Comment: can you give an example, so for row 2 you would have 3 tasks in that time frame?

Comment: Correct. So you would have a timeline on the X axis divided into half-hour intervals, and the number of tasks in each interval will be histogrammed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code, I convert to timestamps first and then do a double loop to find all overlaps, which then increment the count.

```
StartTime <- c("8:30","8:25","10:15","11:30","12:15","12:30","1:00","2:35")
EndTime <- c("9:00","10:05","12:00","1:05","2:06","2:58","3:30","4:00")
TaskTimes <- data.frame(StartTime,EndTime)

TaskTimes$s <- strptime(TaskTimes$StartTime, "%H:%M")
TaskTimes$e <- strptime(TaskTimes$EndTime, "%H:%M")

s <- as.numeric(strptime('0:00', "%H:%M"))
df <- data.frame(tick = seq(s, s + 24 * 60 * 60, 30 * 60), count = 0) # increment half hour
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(TaskTimes)) {
    # overlap (StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)
    if (df$tick[i] <= TaskTimes$e[j] & df$tick[i] + 30 * 60 >= TaskTimes$s[j]) {
      df$count[i] <- df$count[i] + 1
    }
  }
}

plot(df)
```

Comment: Try barplot(df$count) to look like a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for each moment of time, with 30 min step, you want to know how many tasks are started and not finished at that moment.

1. Transform each start and end from string to integer number (number of minutes), for example "8:30" to 510.  Let the array names be `starts` and `ends`.
2. Make an array temp[1440], fill it by zeros.  If all starts are different, set `temp[starts]<-1`, `temp[ends]<-temp[ends]-1`.
3. Calculate `cumsum(temp)`